# Multiple queries with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Good Day!
I am unfamiliar with multiple queries with PHP and MySQL and I haven't found an answer to my question (maybe it's not possible to do?).
I have a database with several tables, and I try to build a multiple query (in PHP) which relies to the result of the previous query. Here is an example of my database:

```
Table1

id:1, first_name: Sally, last_name:Meyers,
id:2, first_name: George, last_name:Smith,
id:3, first_name: Peter, last_name:Gabriel,
id:4, first_name: John, last_name:Doe

Table2

type: hystory, number: 123456789, last_name:Meyers,
type: suspense, number: 1321465447, last_name: Smith,
type: sci-fi, number: 931213246, last_name: Gabriel,
type: suspense, number: 555221321, last_name: Doe

Table3

title: War and Peace, year: 1997, author: 3, type: hystory,
title: Justice for all!, year: 2014, author: 1, type: suspense,
title: Time lost, year: 2001, author: 2, type: sci-fi,
title: The cold war, year: 1981, author: 3, type: suspense,
```

My query would be something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Table1 WHERE id=3 AND SELECT sci-fi FROM Table2 WHERE last_name = [result of the first query] AND SELECT title FROM Table3 WHERE type = [result of the second query];
```

All I want to do, at the end, is to return (via AJAX) a single JSON object to Javascript composed of the selected elements from the database.
Can you help building this multiple query, please ?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Expected vs actual result?]

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: it's not clear what the end result should be, and your example SQL doesn't really make enough sense to clarify that. Nor is it clear what you've done to try and solve this beyond creating some very vague pseudo-code.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question (see last sentence). Thanks!  :)

Comment: I don't really get your question but i think you'll need to use JOIN in your query : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: You'd have to do each seperately, though I think this really could be done with `JOIN`s. [Here is a good representation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: If you need to select data from multiple tables, use table joins. Using `PHP \PDO`, for instance, you are able to run any correctly formed MySQL syntax, so you may test your queries in MySQL Workbench or other tool first. Then you will need to consider prepared MySQL queries and binding parameters. Links: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you need  a  join with the 3 table eg:

```
  SELECT first_name
      , last_name 
  FROM Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.last_name = Table1.last_name
  INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.type = Table2.type 
  WHERE Table1.id=3
```

Comment: This is what I needed! Sorry if I was not clear. We learn every day! :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT foo.first_name, foo.last_name, bar.title
FROM table1 as foo
JOIN table2 as bar on foo.last_name = bar.last_name
JOIN table3 as cat on bar.type = cat.type
WHERE foo.id=3 and bar.type="sci-fi"
```

I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with JSON conversion...

```
SELECT json_object('FirstName', t1.first_name, 'LastName', t1.last_name,'Sci-Fi', t2.sci-fi, 'Title',t3.title)
 FROM Table1 t1
join Table t2
on t1.last_name = t2.last_Name
join Table t3
on t2.type = t3.type
WHERE t1.id=3
```